# (Co)homology of $S^2×S^2/ℤ_2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

[Cohomology of $S^2\times S^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788341/cohomology-of-s2-times-s2-mathbbz-2)

I was looking at this question, the accepted answer uses the homology of the space to find the cohomology. I was wondering how one could compute the homology of an orbit space like this in the first place?

"The product of two spheres admits a diagonal $ℤ_2$ action, $(x, y)\mapsto(−x,−y)$" - describe the homology groups of the orbit space of this free action.

Comment: As long as you can construct a nice enough cell decomposition or triangulation of $S^2 \times S^2$ has, you can derive a cellular decomposition or triangulation of the orbit, and then proceed from there directly using cellular or simplicial homology.

Comment: @RolfHoyer I am sorry, I am not sure I understand you completely. Lets say I do a cellular decomposition of $S2 x S2$

$S2xS2$ has a one $e^2$ and one $e^0$ cell for each S2. So the cell structure for $S2 \times S2$ is given by the cells

$e^0 \times e^0$, $e^2 \times e^2$, two $e^0 \times e^2$.

Comment: @RolfHoyer I am unsure how I can use this to find a decomposition of the orbit

Comment: That is one decomposition, but it isn't the only one.  In order to get a nice cellular structure on the orbit, you need the group action to never produce a non-identity self-map from a cell to itself.  That way, when you go to the quotient it just identifies cells without needing to do any folding.  I would recommend subdividing your decomposition further.  It should suffice to use the decomposition of $S^2$ into two cells in each of dimensions 0,1,2, I think.

Comment: @RolfHoyer I am afraid I still don't see how that will help with finding the homology of the orbit space. Perhaps I am not understanding you properly - once I have a cellular decomposition of $S2 \times S2$ (say I use yours and now have 36(?) cells) - I don't see how I could use this for the orbit.

Due to the nature of $Z_2$; I assume in the orbit space, there are half the amount of cells. But I can't see how I use that to compute the homology. I have tried writing it out and am not sure once I get the 18 "classes." Or perhaps I am not getting you at all. I am sorry to bother you this much.

Comment: The next step would be to form the cellular chain complex (which should have 18 generators overall ranging from dimensions 0 through 4) and compute differentials.  This looks pretty unwieldy so there probably is an easier way, though.

Comment: Perhaps by using the homology of $S2 \times S2$ itself.

Comment: The only options I can see off the top of my head are 1) brute force with the 18 cells. 2) use the method of the linked accepted answer, which doesn't take the homology groups as granted but uses a pretty robust set of tricks, or 3) figure out how to get a spectral sequence to do the work for you maybe?

Comment: @RolfHoyer (3) works. I would write it up if and only if it is of interest to OP - I worry I would be writing something complicated and somewhat abstract for little gain for others. The cellular chain complex is not so impossible to calculate here (I remember doing this explicitly around the time of that original thread), but I do not have the energy to try again.

Comment: You should be able to find a smaller $(\Bbb Z/2)$-invariant cellular decomposition (yours is actually invariant under the (non-free) action of $D_8$, and in particular gives rise to a cellular chain complex on $\Bbb{RP}^2 \times \Bbb{RP}^2$, which is the quotient by $\Bbb Z/2 \times \Bbb Z/2$).

Comment: @MikeMiller I am afraid I am not familiar with spectral sequences. I think I am probably going to brute force my way through. 

I will see if I find an easier way, and post an answer if I do.

Comment: @ShellyB I hope you do - I would love to see such an answer! :) I think calculating the boundary map won't be hard, but you'll get a kind of nasty chain complex. (Usually, cellular chains don't help get the ring structure, but if you care about that as in the other answer you can see that all products are zero for silly reasons.) I think I might try to write up a relatively expository answer using those at some point, but don't expect it any time soon.